# How to dynamically resize TableView Cell Height and TableView Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with two cells, The content of the tableview cell will change and will be dynamic, so I want to dynamically resize the tableview cell and according to the tableview cell height I want to calculate the height of tableview.
My tableview is taking an extra space while rendering the cells.

**Can anyone help me with the approach on how to set the tableview height according to the tableview cell height**

```
class Recent_WH_acitivityCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var wh_activity_tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var wh_activity_table_ht: NSLayoutConstraint!

let cells = 2
var maxHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    wh_activity_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    wh_activity_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func setData()
{
    wh_activity_tableView.reloadData()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
{
    let height = min(self.contentView.frame.height, maxHeight)
    return CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width, height: height)
}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(contentView.frame, UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 15, right: 0))
}}

extension Recent_WH_acitivityCell : UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recent_wh_data_cell", for: indexPath) as! Recent_WH_Data_cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Here is the Screenshot**

Please look into the highlighted part.

[image]

Comment: Off topic , swift best practice  don't encourage such naming `recent_wh_data_cell` , prefers `recentWhDataCell`

Comment: @Tobi I think right now my main concern is on the problem on which I am stuck and not on the naming convention

Comment: a little tip as noted off topic ^_^ you are free to work with it or not

Comment: Yaa sure, I will correct it :)

Comment: you want the cells to fit 100% the size of the table view ?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate the tableview height dynamically according to the height of the tableview cells

Comment: well theoretically speaking thats impossible since the table already initialised   on the layout however you can set a footer constraint to the bottom tab bar and use its outlet and change it based on how much is you cell height taking , or you can expand the height of your cells to match 100% of the view or just simply set empty footer view which make it more even reliable

Comment: I think it is doable, just I am missing something

Comment: as the deleted answer try the empty view way it might solve your problem

Comment: everything is but there is always the better choice for each case and i am with the empty view footer method

Comment: No it didnt solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Assign constraint align top and bottom to parent view. and then use one call as header cell like "Sell your stock" and use cell as normal cell under section, So you can get proper output as your requirement.

Also assign height constraint and IBOutlet it and calculate number of cell * cell height + header height = tableview height constraint

And then set accordingly `UIScrollview` `contentsize`.

For example one cell height is 80 and number of cell 5 then scrollview content size is = other item height + header height + (80 * 5)
tableview height constraint is  =  header height + (80 * 5)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a self sizing `UITableView` like this:

```
class SelfSizingTableView: UITableView {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure to set up the cell's constraints correctly (full constraints from the top to the bottom of the cell) and enable self-sizing cells in your view controller like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```